# Getting objects in an array that has a specific property

Tags: arrays, loops, typescript, object, filter

Alright, so I am trying to make an ArtistPage, and I need to put *all the albums by that artist*, on the page. I put a property called artistName in each album as a way of kinda referencing it but idk if that is the correct practice.

This is the results of a variable called ***getAlbums*** that i have in the code that returns an array of objects, which are all the albums in the 'database' -->

```
[
 {name: "The Cool", genre: "Hip-Hop", artistName: "Lupe Fiasco", year: "2006", isExplicit: "true", …}
 {name: "Food & Liquor", artistName: "Lupe Fiasco", genre: "Hip-Hop", year: "2006", isExplicit: "true", …}
 {name: "Flume", artistName: "Flume", genre: "Electronic", year: "2012", isExplicit: "true", …}
 {name: "Skin", artistName: "Flume", isExplicit: "true", genre: "Electronic", year: "2016", …}
 {name: "Hybrid Theory", artistName: "Linkin Park", isExplicit: "true", genre: "Nu-Metal", year: "2000", …}
 {name: "Views", artistName: "Drake", genre: "Hip-Hop", year: "2016", isExplicit: "true", …}
 {name: "2014 Forest Hills Drive", artistName: "J.Cole", isExplicit: "true", genre: "Hip-Hop", year: "2014", …}
 {name: "Marshal Matthers LP", artistName: "Eminem", isExplicit: "true", genre: "Hip-Hop", year: "2000", …}
]
```

I'm using a function to try and loop though all the properties but its wrong ahh.
It only returns one album

```
  getAlbumsByArtist(artistName: any) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.getAlbums.length - 1; i++) {
      if (this.getAlbums[i].artistName === this.artistName) {
        return this.getAlbums[i];
      }
    }
  }
```

So if I wanted to retrieve ALL objects that has the property "artistName: Flume" in this array, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: It looks like you're using typescript, is that correct?

Comment: yep. with angular 4 particulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
getAlbumsByArtist (artistName: any) {
  return this.getAlbums.filter(album => album.artistName === artistName);
}
```

You could even define a generic method to search by any property like this:

```
getAlbumsByProperty (property: string, value: any) {
  return this.getAlbums.filter(album => album[property] === value);
}
```

and call that like `database.getAlbumsByProperty('artistName', 'Flume')`

Comment: I can't believe i forgot about the filter method ahhh. Thanks a bunch man that was a direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HigherOrder functions in this case.

```
var albums=array.filter(album=> {
    if(album.artistName==='Flume') {
    return album;
  }
})
console.log("ans", albums);
```

Working Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/241wkzph/